# using the plot function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot the relative error (y -axis) and the time steps on the (x-axis). I am using the LSM algorithm to price American options and I do not receive any output on the plot when I run my program and I am not sure why. Here is my code:

```
clear;
clc;
r = 0.06;
q = 0.03;
S0 = 40;
T = 1;
sigma = 0.4;
K = 40;
N = 10000;
M = 100000;
k = 1;

[Call,Put] = blsprice(S0,K,r,T,sigma,q);

for i = 1:200
    u(i) = LSM(T,r,q,sigma,K,S0,i,M,k);
    relative_error(i) = abs(Call - u(i))/Call;
    hold on
    plot(i,relative_error(i))
end
```

Comment: add a function like plot.show()...  (not sure which language is this piece of code written in...)

Comment: @ADITYA where do I add that exactly?

Comment: before you end or after end

Comment: do it after end...

Comment: but in matlab it should work

Comment: refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_plotting.htm

Comment: That didn't seem to work but no worries

Comment: Either put `plot` outside of your loop or use [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html). [MATLAB's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html) is pretty comprehensive and I would highly recommend reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing one point at a time to the Matlab plot function. The plot function works by getting as inputs a series of points and drawing a line between them. With one point it can't possibly do so. Either invoke the plot function after the for loop or use:

```
plot(i,relative_error(i),'r*')
```

to clearly mark every point.

Comment: How about using line instead of plot? I wanted to graph it as a line and not a scatter plot

Comment: If you answer my question I will accept your answer

Comment: I would then suggest you remove the `hold on` and `plot` lines from the loop and add `plot(1:size(relative_error,2),relative_error(1:size(relative_error,2)))` after the `end` line